# innerHTML property is not changing after JS function

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm a fresher in JS, so I have the following task: Some text is given on a page and when a user wants to find a set of characters or string by adding this string in a window and then clicking "search", this string should be marked as bold in our text each time it is met.
Looking through my code I'm almost sure that the function is working, but after the function has finished, the bold strings just blink for a moment and the text returns to its initial status.

Please help me to find out my mistake.
Here's the code.

```js
function look(a) {
  var str = document.getElementById("original").innerHTML;
  var len = a.text.value.length;
  var begin = str.indexOf(a.text.value);
  var final = str;

  if (begin == -1) {
    alert("No matches");
    return false;
  }
  if (begin > -1) {
    var count = 0;
    final = str.substring(count, begin) + "<b>" + a.text.value + "</b>" + str.substring(begin + len + 1, str.length);
    while (begin != -1) {
      begin = str.indexOf(a.text.value, begin + len);
      if (begin == -1) break;
      final = final.substring(count, begin) + "<b>" + a.text.value + "</b>" + str.substring(begin + len + 1, str.length);
    }

    document.getElementById("original").innerHTML = final;

    return true;
  }

}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="original" type="text">Some given text</span>
  <br/>
  <form name="search" onsubmit="return look(this)">
    <p>Enter text to search<input type="text" name="text"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="search"></p>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `true` on successfully finding the text span makes the form to be submitted. You need to return `false` to make the form invalidate the submission. This is the updated code, I have changed the return statement out of the `if-else` block and returned `false` either way. Another way is to make submit button as `input[type='button']` and register an `onclick` event listener to it.

```
    function look(a)
    {
        var str=document.getElementById("original").innerHTML;
        var len=a.text.value.length;
        var begin=str.indexOf(a.text.value);
        var final=str;

        if (begin==-1){
            alert("No matches"); 
        }
        if (begin>-1){
            var count=0;
            final=str.substring(count,begin)+"<b>"+a.text.value+"</b>"+str.substring(begin+len+1, str.length);
            while(begin!=-1){ 
                begin=str.indexOf(a.text.value,begin+len);
                if(begin==-1) break;
                final=final.substring(count, begin)+"<b>"+a.text.value+"</b>"+str.substring(begin+len+1, str.length);
           } 

            document.getElementById("original").innerHTML=final;


        }

        return false;

    }
```

Comment: This is the elaborated answer of the previous one !

Answer (score 1):

The page is refreshing! By default, forms refresh the page. You can use the return value of the on submit function to stop this default behavior: just return false.

```js
   function look(a)
        {
            var str=document.getElementById("original").innerHTML;
            var len=a.text.value.length;
            var begin=str.indexOf(a.text.value);
            var final=str;
            
            if (begin==-1){
                alert("No matches");
                return  false; 
            }
            if (begin>-1){
                var count=0;
                final=str.substring(count,begin)+"<b>"+a.text.value+"</b>"+str.substring(begin+len+1, str.length);
                while(begin!=-1){ 
                    begin=str.indexOf(a.text.value,begin+len);
                    if(begin==-1) break;
                    final=final.substring(count, begin)+"<b>"+a.text.value+"</b>"+str.substring(begin+len+1, str.length);
               } 
                
                document.getElementById("original").innerHTML=final;
                
                return false;
            }

        }
```

```html
<body>
    <span id="original" type="text">
            Some given text
            </span>
    <br/>
    <form name="search" onsubmit="look(this); return false;">
            <p>
                Enter text to search<input type="text" name="text">
                
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="search">
                
            </p>
            
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```